# How to find -exec cd in linux / unix

Tags: linux, unix, find, exec

I'm searching for a config folder, and trying to change to that directory:

```
find . -name "config" -exec cd {} \;
```

There is one match, `./my-applications/config`, but after I try this it says:

```
find: `cd': No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The command `cd` is a shell built-in, not found in `/bin` or `/usr/bin`.

Of course, you can't change directory to a file and your search doesn't limit itself to directories.  And the `cd` command would only affect the executed command, not the parent shell that executes the `find` command.

Use:

```
cd $(find . -name config -type d | sed 1q)
```

Note that if your directory is not found, you'll be back in your home directory when the command completes.  (The `sed 1q` ensures you only pass one directory name to `cd`; the Korn shell `cd` takes two values on the command and does something fairly sensible, but Bash ignores the extras.)

Comment: Some OSes like Solaris do have a cd in /usr/bin but of course that doesn't change the fact they can't change the current shell directory.

Comment: excellent. i didn't realize that cd was a shell built in. that explains it!

Comment: If you need the _cd_ and another command, you can always use `sh -c`, for example `find . -name "config" -type d -exec sh -c "cd {}; git pull" \;`

Answer (score 5):

In case you have more than one config directory:

```
select config in $(find . -name config -type d)
do
  cd $config
  break
done
```

Comment: i know this is old, but `select` should be `for` ?

Comment: @Roger I believe `select` is better than `for` here. If there is more than one `config` directory, the user can chose which one to `cd` in while with the accepted answer, the first one found is used, which is quite an arbitrary choice.

Comment: Maybe it’s bash? Doesn’t seem to work in sh.

Comment: @Roger Are you running an ancient Bourne shell ? How does it fail ?

Answer (score 2):

`find` runs `-exec` programs as subprocesses and subprocesses cannot affect their parent process. So, it cannot be done. You may want to try

```
cd `find . -name "config"`
```

Comment: Better to use `$(...)` than backticks.

Comment: better to do a `find . -type d...` so that you don't try to `cd` into a file :-)